# i want to recognize arabic font from an image can anyone help me plese image is below

Tags: fonts, arabic, font-family, urdu

[image: Surah Font]

i want to know which font is used in the image above.i tried using online services but non of them worked. and i also tried all fonts which are available in "in page" but none of them worked ether.or if you know the way to find the font family of the text in image it will be much much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, browsers have "national language" support of only one type of font, normally it also requires UTF-8 charset as the partial document or complete document header.
The partial document (markup container element) requires the use of ISO-639-1 international two letter language code on the lang attribute of the element for HTML or XML.
Aside the browser, the OS System may have particular language support that will use a set of OS supplied fonts.
If you have Arabic fonts in your OS , you use the font library file name for the font. Don't forget to set the markup element "dir" attribute to RTL because Arabic is start at right to left and top to bottom.

Comment: i think you did not get it. i just want to know the name of the font used in image.

Comment: i cannot recognize it eather by using online font recognizers or any other thing

Comment: Do you know any "employed" graphic artists with Arabic as their native language and culture. Much of advertising is image construction and aspect ratio changing of image parts.

Comment: i dont, that is why i posted it on SO

Comment: Of it cannot be found try matching it by googling (and use the images Google search)"Islamic Arabic fonts download".  https://www.designyourway.net/drb/34-free-arabic-fonts-available-for-download/